git branch -r --no-merged lists already merged branches
We keep our kickstart code in a git repository so it is consistent across all kickstart servers.  We have a small script to display all current branches, ask which one you want to use and then pulls that down and makes sure the code is readable by all.  A portion of the code:
git checkout main >/dev/null 2>&1
git fetch --all >/dev/null 2>&1
git pull >/dev/null 2>&1
git branch -r --no-merged
echo "  main"

Instead of listing just the unmerged branches, it lists just about every branch we've ever had.  What am I doing wrong?

They’re listing the (local) merged branches? Not the remote ones (-r?)

No, it lists just about all branches that have been merged.
Our git version is 1.8.3.1

For example, it lists:  origin/24-http-boot  which is a branch I worked on about a month ago and merged in.  I deleted all but the main and two currently open branches from a local kickstart server and it still lists about 30.

But that name is a remote-tracking branch name. It’s one of the “remote ones”. Try git fetch --prune origin.

That took out a lot!  I'm down to five.  There are three open branches.  I can live with five!  Thanks!

git pull does a git fetch so what is the git fetch step for? Seems like a waste of time to fetch twice.

Plus, if you said git pull --prune you'd remove the stale remote tracking branches from your local repo.

Do you actually merge the branches are you do squashing them? Squashing is not a real merge.

Can you please explain what process you follow to "merge your branches" ? as @knittl indicated: if you mean "merging pull requests" using gitlab or github (or an equivalent service), and you follow a "squash and merge" process, then the result is not actual merges in the history of your main branch.

Your question is not enough to fix error.

We actually merge them.  I don't think we have any that are squashed.  I only did a git fetch --all because I wanted to make sure I retrieved all of the remote information.

Sorry, my comment above was a little wrong.  When we create a new branch, in the gui interface, we check the check box which says to squash this when merged.  When we merge, we do: git checkout main;git pull origin main;git merge branch;git push origin main.


Instead of listing just the unmerged branches, it lists just about every branch we've ever had.

This is likely happening because Git doesn't actually merge branches, but instead merges commits. Take any branch that you see which you expect should not be there, and try this command:
git log main..<some-branch-name>

This will show you all the commits that are "on" that branch that aren't "on" main. If the output of that command is blank, then by definition that branch is fully merged.
Some reasons that most of the branches could be "not merged" are:

When merging the branches, a strategy is used which rewrites the commits getting merged in. Some common merge strategies in popular tools are called things like: squash merge, rebase merge or semi-linear merge, and rebase fast-forward. If any of those strategies were used, and if the original feature branch was not rewritten and also not deleted, then they will all be sitting out there as unmerged.
At some point in the past, your main branch was rewritten, but the feature branches were not.
After the feature branches were merged, more commits were added to those feature branches, perhaps due to branch name re-use.
If the workflow is such that users happen to push a lot of branches for work in progress before settling on a final branch at the end, you might just have a bunch of old work in progress branches that the devs never bothered to clean up.

You can easily prove if #1 is the culprit: when you run the command above, search for the commits that are listed, to see if they also exist in main, but with different commit IDs. If the commit messages, authors and dates are the same, but they have different commit dates and commit IDs, then this points to a rebase merge or rebase fast-forward strategy that also does not rewrite the feature branch before doing the merge.
Side Note: if #1 is the reason, consider deleting your feature branches after merging them into main. (This is a setting on most tools that offer Pull/Merge requests.)

Another possibility, but it's so unlikely I'm just making it a comment, for now, is that main is the wrong branch, and isn't the branch that all of those feature branches were merged into. I've seen this before when a repository uses both master and main, and main isn't actually updated very often.

No, main is the correct "master."  There are only two of us that are active in making changes.  We have three current branches off of main.  On one of the kickstart servers when running git branch -r, it lists those three plus 4 more that were merged in to main.  I will work on checking what the log operation shows.

When examining active branches vs open merged requests and talking with my co-worker, we decided when her merged in a few of those branches, he forgot to check the delete the branch.  I checked the active branches that do not have an open merge request and saw that the changes were incorporated into main.  So, they had been merged.  Thanks so much for the help!      Just a side note, I see that a couple of people voted down my question.  Why would they do that when it is a problem we were having and I was seeking the answer to?  I just want to make sure I understand the mechanics.

@user2664304 Glad this helped. I'm not exactly sure why the question was downvoted. Some people are more strict about what constitutes a good question than others. I think it's probably because your question doesn't have enough information to accurately answer it. Even my answer offers a bunch of different possible reasons, due to not quite enough information. Perhaps had you provided an example graph showing a branch next to main we could have had a more exact answer. But, depending on your starting Git knowledge you may not have known how to do that, so I personally wouldn't DV for that.
